# Firebase dynamic link short url returns nil ios

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I am facing an issue with Firebase dynamic link. The link is generated from the backend. and it's working perfectly in android. but in iOS when I shared the dynamic link on whatsapp or messages app on iPhone. and tap on the link app is opened. and our following function is called in Appdelegate. and after that firebase function is called with the received URL. and the firebase functions return nil. But when I open that link from the safari app is opened and that same firebase function returns the deeplink URL. I have searched alot but did not find the solution. I am using firebase 7.11 version pods.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        if let incomingUrl = userActivity.webpageURL{
            print("Incoming URL is \(incomingUrl)")
            
            let linkHandled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(incomingUrl) { (dynamicLink, error) in
//                guard error == nil else{
//                    print("Found an error! \(error!.localizedDescription)")
//                    return
//                }
                print("error \(error)")
                print("dynamicLink \(dynamicLink)") // It returns nil when app open from whatsapp or any 3rd party app.
               
            }
            if linkHandled{
                return true
            }else{
                
                return false
            }
        }
        return false
}
```

I have also received the following error in both cases.

```
Error Domain=com.firebase.dynamicLinks Code=403 "(null)" UserInfo={code=403, message=Requests to this API firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com method google.firebase.dynamiclinks.v1.DynamicLinksService.GetIosReopenAttribution are blocked., status=PERMISSION_DENIED, details=( 
{ 
"@type" = "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo"; 
domain = "googleapis.com"; 
metadata = { 
consumer = "projects/37866531840"; 
service = "firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com"; 
}; 
reason = "API_KEY_SERVICE_BLOCKED"; 
} 
)}
```

Comment: Resolved. I have created the new firebase project for this. Now its working.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add your custom domains in your info.plist file with FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains parameter like image below.

[image: info.plist]

Comment: I am not using any custom domain. I have firebase provided xyz.page.link/ that type domain.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set AppBundle id as deepLinkURLScheme as like below in AppDelegate class under function didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
let kAppBundleID = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier
FirebaseOptions.defaultOptions()?.deepLinkURLScheme = kAppBundleID
```

Please try with this.

Reference:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/create

By default, Dynamic Links uses your app's bundle identifier as the URL scheme needed to open up your application. We recommend staying with this default value to keep your implementation simple.